Automate the Creation of Dummy Values for Missing Data Across Multiple Columns in Python
I have the following dataframe in pandas:
  a    b    c
1 3    Nan  3
2 2    1    Nan
3 Nan  3    5
4 3    2    Nan
5 Nan  Nan  2

I need to recode my data to look like this:
  a    b    c
1 0    1    0
2 0    0    1
3 1    0    0
4 0    0    1
5 1    1    0

Is there a way to code in Python so that it automatically recodes a set of columns to do this?
In other words take the following code (or a piece of code that achieves the same output):
df_miss_a = df["a"].isna().astype(int)

And apply it to both "a", "b", and "c" automatically?

Just do df = df.isna().astype(int)
